# Replace "variable (changing) text in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, joomla

This question can be very easy to answer or doesn't have an answer at all.

I am updating a website, that already has a lot of articles, to be mobile compatible.  One of the problems I have is the size of the images. So, I created a new CSS class that takes care of re-sizing the images in a responsive way.

The problem I have is that most images contain `width="XXX"` and `height="XXX"`. For my CSS class to work I need to get rid of both the width and height specifications.

I am doing this in `Joomla` using a nice Database text replacer component, so I don't need to know the actual REPLACE syntax, but how to target all the different widths and heights.

I can certainly do something like this:

```
Original: width="
Replace for: (empty)
```

The problem is how to target all the different values that go inside `"` and `"`.  I have tried using *, but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea about how I could do it, either via this component or directly using MySQL syntax?

Comment: Does the Joomla text replace support regular expressions? If so, the regex would probably look like `width="[^"]+"`

Comment: What does 'most images contain width="XXX" and height="XXX"' mean? Are you talking about metadata stored in the image files, attributes of the `<img>` tag, properties of a CSS class, or what?

Comment: Yes, something like <img width="300" height="300" src="..." alt="">

Comment: You need a specific SQL syntax for it? Or something related to *Database text replacer component*?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - Yes, it does.  I'll try out your expression

Back in a Flash - Actually it doesn't really matter, using the component is normally easier, but if this cannot be done using the component, an SQL expression will do too.

Comment: I tried @MichaelBerkowski 's answer and it worked beautifully! That was the easiest and best option I think. So, if someone has the same problem, and is using Joomla, you can replace anything using DBReplacer by Nonumber and using Michael's code. Thank you everyone for your help! –

Answer (score 0):

There's a `MySQL`'s user-defined function named [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp). The only drawback is that you'd need to rebuild your `MySQL` server.

Another option is to create a rough PHP script, which'll loop through the entire database searching for the attributes and update those rows with the replaced string.